# How to validate client certificate generate in AWS Gateway in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, certificate, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I'm use .NETCore version 5, and use too API Gateway from AWS, but how validate Client Certificate on API ?

Configure a backend HTTPS server to verify the client certificate in ECS ? pipeline ? or image docker ?

Examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#generate-client-certificate

With resolve implementation validation client certificate in API use .NETCore 5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would have to run an HTTPS server on your backend, and configure it to verify the client certificate.

Comment: I am use pipeline devops azure with publish in aws ecs, how to implementation with ecs ?